# Gitlab on a 2FA + openssh secured Server

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys, openssh

```
System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Server 

Gitlab: 11.7.5-ee
```

Got a new local server (deep learning rig) which should also house Gitlab as this machine can easily handle that on the side.

The server must be of course as secure as possible, so I changed server configuration to make logins only possible for `ssh-key + google 2FA` (according to this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04

Afterwards installed gitlab and imported project, set up CI, added ssh-keys. On the webinterface everything is working perfectly fine, also CI's are running through and web-portal-login with again `2FA` is working as intended. sidenote: Gitlab itself is only reachable via internal IP (intended).

Locally I switched branches with :

`git remote set-url origin git@IP:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

BUT, neither clone, nor pull, nor push is working now. I (and also all other users) get   :

`git@IP's password:`

Of course I don't have that password.

Making

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check

Checking GitLab subtasks ...

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell: ... GitLab Shell version >= 8.4.4 ? ... OK (8.4.4)
Running /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Redis available via internal API: OK

Access to /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Gitaly ...

Gitaly: ... default ... OK

Checking Gitaly ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Sidekiq: ... Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Incoming Email ...

Incoming Email: ... Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Incoming Email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP: ... LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab App ...

Git configured correctly? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config up to date? ... yes
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Uploads directory exists? ... yes
Uploads directory has correct permissions? ... yes
Uploads directory tmp has correct permissions? ... yes
Init script exists? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Init script up-to-date? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Projects have namespace: ...
Administrator / salesbeat ... yes
Redis version >= 2.8.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.3.5 ? ... yes (2.5.3)
Git version >= 2.18.0 ? ... yes (2.18.1)
Git user has default SSH configuration? ... yes
Active users: ... 4
Elasticsearch version 5.6 - 6.x? ... skipped (elasticsearch is disabled)

Checking GitLab App ... Finished


Checking GitLab subtasks ... Finished
```

Checking via the sh -Tv git@192.168.0.113

```
sh -Tv git@192.168.0.113
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.113 [192.168.0.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.113:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:TubIbvzKzAsDNbW4WYmmLss4Jo7q089SmJmhdvdyhl8
debug1: Host '192.168.0.113' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:8Nkt7JyhE9zQKv6EIXfSMRLgzg8dh+eSzuPqvrSgpLw /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@192.168.0.113's password:
```

Can't find a solution and running out of ideas. It looks like the key is detected and offered, but then it goes straight to Next authentication method: password
Only reason that I can think of is the 2FA from the server itself, but I obviously can't disable that one due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSH log indicates that the `keyboard-interactive` step (which would include the TOTP token prompt) did not actually do anything, probably meaning that your TOTP setup is incorrect or incomplete. This part is handled by libpam-google-authenticator; you might be able to find additional logs in `/var/log/auth.log` (or elsewhere depending on your system's logging setup).

My hunch: the setup shown in the tutorial creates a .google_authenticator file, make sure it ended up in the right place (`/var/opt/gitlab` if you are using the standard locations).

Since this is a troubleshooting operation, I can't provide a complete answer, but this should give you a few more things to check.

---

Also, just a heads up, this is probably not doable in the way you envision.

GitLab works internally by using a single system account `git` and associating all of the SSH keys with that account. Authenticating via SSH with a specific public key allows GitLab to look up which GitLab user this key belongs to, to apply the correct identity and authorization for you on the application level (i.e. for Git operations).

The PAM module for Google Authenticator knows nothing of this. It can only associate a single TOTP key for any system account, meaning that all of the GitLab users would be sharing the same tokens - this strongly reduces the benefit of using TOTP tokens in the first place.

Side note, I have never seen a Git server that required TOTP in addition to SSH key authentication. It is also incredibly annoying in practice because it means every Git operation will prompt for a token, whereas with a proper SSH key setup with a key agent you will only be prompted once per day (give or take). You might want to consider lowering your standards and accepting the two factors of encrypted SSH key and key passphrase (which is a much higher level of security than just a password for sure).